# Parent screen looks broken when child content is included

Tags: moqui

While working on tutorial from the book "Making Apps with Moqui", in part 1 under "Try Sub-Content", my tutorial.xml screen looks like below:

```
<screen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://moqui.org/xsd/xml-screen-1.4.xsd"
    require-authentication="false" include-child-content="true">
  <widgets>
    <label type="h1" text="Hello world!"/>
    <subscreens-active/> 
  </widgets>
</screen>
```

The child screen located at url localhost:8080/apps/tutorial/hello.html works as expected. When I go to parent screen with url localhost:8080/apps/tutorial , my parent screen has an error message after the hello world message as shown below:

> Hello world!
>   Tried to render subscreen in screen [component://tutorial/screen/tutorial.xml] but there is no subscreens.@default-item, and no more valid subscreen names in the screen path [[apps, tutorial]]

Is it an expected response or am I making some mistake? In my opinion, parent screen should not show this error message.

Comment: Have you checked the errata for the book to see if there has been an updated code snippet?

Comment: There is no errata of this book. The latest code is similar to the one I posted above. The tutorial from the book is uploaded here as well: http://www.moqui.org/framework/docs/Tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial code has been updated to address this in the latest version of the book (0.94), available for download from moqui.org. Similar changes still need to be made to the Tutorial.html page (or actually the cwiki file used to generate that page), i.e. that page has not yet been updated on the moqui.org web site.

Whatever the case, this is a good example of what happens when using sub-screens or sub-content without specifying a default or putting the full path to sub-screen or sub-content in the URL.

Comment: The tutorial page on the moqui.org site is now updated to improve the examples and clarify this point. The latest version of the Making Apps with Moqui book (0.95) also has some small changes to help clarify this.

Comment: David, thanks  for clarification and updating the books as well as tutorial. It worked fine for me now.